# ASP CustomValidator fails and Modal doesn't clear from screen

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, customvalidator

I am adding a new field to a form. The form is used to update a status from not approved to approved.The goal is to make sure that if no changes are made but the update button is clicked, an error is displayed and no update is processed. This did work before I added the new field and switched from a `RequiredFieldValidator` to a `CustomValidator`.

*The Problem*

Now, when no changes are made to the drop downs the modal closes but the rest of the window is grayed out and the application seems to hang.

This is <strike>a bit over my head</strike> a great learning experience.

**EDIT:**

Error from the console

```
Doc-Comp-Composition-Templates:348 Uncaught TypeError: $(...).ddlCS is not a function
    at ValidateStatusChange_ClientValidate (Doc-Comp-Composition-Templates:348)
    at eval (eval at CustomValidatorEvaluateIsValid (ScriptResource.axd?d=nv7asgRUU0tRmHNR2D6t1FZw7wze8nmx-kJRmw2XEjbK3oXSAIyhKQNPF6n1kyJ-XavItdyBmyr8jQKkgUwJ4hvE-EOowyd5E-dQMLMfuYhYi3DooAGZ6tCMyoNO-1bI0OD14u047d3MStBJK15cjQ2&t=fffffffff974e48e:450), <anonymous>:1:1)
    at HTMLSpanElement.CustomValidatorEvaluateIsValid [as evaluationfunction] (ScriptResource.axd?d=nv7asgRUU0tRmHNR2D6t1FZw7wze8nmx-kJRmw2XEjbK3oXSAIyhKQNPF6n1kyJ-XavItdyBmyr8jQKkgUwJ4hvE-EOowyd5E-dQMLMfuYhYi3DooAGZ6tCMyoNO-1bI0OD14u047d3MStBJK15cjQ2&t=fffffffff974e48e:450)
    at ValidatorValidate (ScriptResource.axd?d=nv7asgRUU0tRmHNR2D6t1FZw7wze8nmx-kJRmw2XEjbK3oXSAIyhKQNPF6n1kyJ-XavItdyBmyr8jQKkgUwJ4hvE-EOowyd5E-dQMLMfuYhYi3DooAGZ6tCMyoNO-1bI0OD14u047d3MStBJK15cjQ2&t=fffffffff974e48e:200)
    at Page_ClientValidate (ScriptResource.axd?d=nv7asgRUU0tRmHNR2D6t1FZw7wze8nmx-kJRmw2XEjbK3oXSAIyhKQNPF6n1kyJ-XavItdyBmyr8jQKkgUwJ4hvE-EOowyd5E-dQMLMfuYhYi3DooAGZ6tCMyoNO-1bI0OD14u047d3MStBJK15cjQ2&t=fffffffff974e48e:119)
    at Sys$WebForms$PageRequestManager$_doPostBackWithOptions [as _doPostBackWithOptions] (ScriptResource.axd?d=JnUc-DEDOM5KzzVKtsL1tRZpRA_LXrniqfBmVmIZ3cAuPpCW1plWZw2RXdO0zo-BiAzza2U9Udple6pVeaDdyS14EzqQJMs1mhrjSf56Z17-S803UF2Z43EZ-6v-WWTiunEhUO4tmGiISgd0nYLoQNVyt3LQvd2TOLU7l5Fq6n-tE3oJIofGXa6OGTnxPRDQ0&t=fffffffffc18b87d:831)
    at ScriptResource.axd?d=D9drwtSJ4hBA6O8UhT6CQi4RxEM3HXQdD1kANRSxcVDQlciZR3AdFzJCI2OSpEJ8btryaMvtylBgqedQo2VFV1HT2WfhU1dHTVqnIz5ypNeiBiXQQMaUQfmxLJUQguR-W97gIReVDFvaBQUHY7tXxFcflqZ4dU-xR3P7jVPaHdY1&t=fffffffffc18b87d:47
    at HTMLInputElement.onclick (Doc-Comp-Composition-Templates:1)
```

**Controls to validate:**

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="ddlCS">Current Status:</label>
  <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlCS" runat="server" CssClass="form-control" 
    ToolTip="Choose Status" Enabled="false" ValidationGroup="gStatusChange" />
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="ddlNS">New Status:</label>
  <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlNS" runat="server" CssClass="form-control"
    ToolTip="Choose Status" ValidationGroup="gStatusChange" />
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="ddlPA">Proof Approval:</label>
  <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlPA" runat="server" CssClass="form-control"
     Tooltip="Choose Proof Status" ValidationGroup="gStatusChange" />
</div>

<div class="col-sm-3">
    <asp:Button ID="btnUpdate" runat="server" Text="Update Status" 
         CssClass="btn btn-primary pull-left" ToolTip="Save Changes" 
         OnClick="btnUpdate_Click"/>
</div>
```

**Validator:**

```
<asp:CustomValidator ID="custvStatusChange" runat="server" Display="None" 
      ValidationGroup="gStatusChange"
      ErrorMessage="Wow what an error!"
      OnServerValidate="ValidateStatusChange_ServerValidate"  
      ClientValidationFunction="ValidateStatusChange_ClientValidate"/>
<asp:ValidationSummary ID="vscustvStatusChange" runat="server" ToolTip="Error Summary" 
      ShowSummary="true" 
      ShowMessageBox="false" 
      CssClass="alert alert-danger" 
      ValidationGroup="gStatusChange" />

<Triggers>
     <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="gvTemplates" 
          EventName="RowCommand"/>
     <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btnUpdate" EventName="Click"/>
</Triggers>
```

**Server-Side Validation:**

```
protected void ValidateStatusChange_ServerValidate(object source, 
   ServerValidateEventArgs args)
    {
        if (ddlCS.SelectedValue == ddlNS.SelectedValue || ddlPA.SelectedIndex == 0)
        {
            args.IsValid = false;
        }
    }
```

**Client-Side Validation:**

```
<script>
    $m = jQuery.noConflict();
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function ValidateStatusChange_ClientValidate(source, args) {
        var cStatus = $(source).ddlCS("select").prop("selectedIndex");
        var nStatus = $(source).ddlNS("select").prop("selectedIndex");
        var pStatus = $(source).ddlPA("select").prop("selectedIndex");

        if (cStatus == nStatus || pStatus == 0) {
            args.IsValid = false;
        } else {
            args.IsValid = true;
        }
    }
    function closeModal() {
        $('#modStatus').modal('hide');
        $('body').removeClass('modal-open');
        $('.modal-backdrop').remove();
    }
    var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();
    prm.add_endRequest(function () {

        function closeModal() {
            $('#modStatus').modal('hide');
            $('body').removeClass('modal-open');
            $('.modal-backdrop').remove();
        }
    });
 </script>
```

**Button Click event:**

```
protected void btnUpdate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Page.Validate("custvStatusChange");
            if (Page.IsValid)
            {
                #region Template Status change
                if (ddlNS.SelectedIndex > 0)
                {
                    if (ddlCS.SelectedValue != ddlNS.SelectedValue)
                    {
                        if (ddlCS.SelectedValue == "5" && hfProofStatus.Value == "N")
                        {
                            lblUpdateStatus.Text = "Proof must be approved before template can be";
                            lblUpdateStatus.CssClass = "text-danger";
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), "Close", "$('#modStatus').modal('hide');$('body').removeClass('modal-open');$('.modal-backdrop').remove();", true);
                            // save and notify
                            DotNetAuth auth = (DotNetAuth)HttpContext.Current.Session["AppSysAuth"];
                            if (CompositionTemplate.UpdateStatus(Convert.ToInt32(hfTemplateID.Value),
                                Convert.ToInt32(ddlNS.SelectedValue), auth.Name, hfFileName.Value))
                            {
                                lblUpdateStatus.Text = "Status change saved";
                                lblUpdateStatus.CssClass = "text-success";
                                BindGrid();
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                lblUpdateStatus.Text = "Error saving status change";
                                lblUpdateStatus.CssClass = "text-danger";
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                #endregion
            }
        }
```

Comment: Check the browser console for possible errors/exceptions.

Comment: thank you @mshsayem I've added the error message

Comment: Sounds like `$(source).ddlCS("select")` is not a proper selector function. You should use `$('#<%= ddlCS.ClientID %>')` or `$(' select [id=<%= ddlCS.ClientID %>]')` as dropdown selector.

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto I used $(' select [id=<%= ddlCS.ClientID %>]') and it worked!! Can you add as an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: @turkaffe Done with that; I just curious why `$m = jQuery.noConflict();` is used, since you're not referencing `$m` anywhere?

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto I inherited the code and haven't made any changes than the ones requested by the client

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `ddlCS()` function (also with `ddlNS()` and `ddlPA()`) is undefined because they're not defined inside jQuery selector of `$(source)`. You should change these lines:

```
var cStatus = $(source).ddlCS("select").prop("selectedIndex");
var nStatus = $(source).ddlNS("select").prop("selectedIndex");
var pStatus = $(source).ddlPA("select").prop("selectedIndex");
```

to these lines below, which uses `ClientID` for each dropdown (since you're not using `ClientIDMode="Static"` attribute, therefore assumed dynamic client ID is in place):

```
var cStatus = $('#<%= ddlCS.ClientID %>').prop("selectedIndex");
var nStatus = $('#<%= ddlNS.ClientID %>').prop("selectedIndex");
var pStatus = $('#<%= ddlPA.ClientID %>').prop("selectedIndex");
```

Or using `select` element selector with `id` attribute set to `ClientID` of each dropdown like this:

```
var cStatus = $('select [id=<%= ddlCS.ClientID %>]').prop("selectedIndex");
var nStatus = $('select [id=<%= ddlNS.ClientID %>]').prop("selectedIndex");
var pStatus = $('select [id=<%= ddlPA.ClientID %>]').prop("selectedIndex");
```